# Generic templatized enum null value

Tags: c++, templates, enums, warnings, clang

**clang++** complains about a variable being uninitialized:

```
template<typename TEnum> void func() {
    TEnum enumVar; 
    // ...
    if(something()) enumVar = someValue();
    // ...
    if(something()) doSomethingWith(enumVar); // <- clang++ tells me 
                                              // enumVar may be uninitialized
}
```

Usually, to avoid this warning, an enum could have a `Unknown = -1` value or something similar - but unfortunately here the enum type is passed by the user as `typename TEnum`, so I don't know whether it contains a "null value".

Is there any way to solve the issue? Or should I just ignore/suppress the warning?

Comment: bool is_something = something() and if(is_something) might help. It may break the logic (the second something might return a different value), hence the warning.

Comment: How about just do `TEnum enumVar = TEnum ();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may initialize the enum:

```
template<typename TEnum> void func() {
    TEnum enumVar = TEnum();
    // TEnum enumVar {}; // C++11 way

    // ...
    if(something()) enumVar = someValue();
    // ...
    if(something()) doSomethingWith(enumVar);
}
```

Note that the enum will have value `0` which may be an invalid value.

Comment: Minor nitpick: this will initialize and assign, so this is inefficient and not good style.

Answer (score 3):

Just always initialize, e.g. with the ternary operator, and then proceed to process it:

```
template<typename TEnum> 
void func() 
{
    TEnum enumVar = something() ?  someValue() : otherValue();
    if (something()) 
        doSomethingWith(enumVar); 
}
```

Obviously, if `something()` is expensive, you could cache it etc., but the point remains: separate initialization from processing.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::optional<E>` takes an almost regular type and regularizes it by defining uninitialized as empty.  It is UB to use if empty, beyond checking it for empty or similsr operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more template parameter to your function template:

```
template<typename TEnum, TEnum nullValue> void func() {
    TEnum enumVar = nullValue;
    // ...
}
```

In C++11 you can also use default template argument:

```
template<typename TEnum, TEnum nullValue = Enum()> void func() {
    TEnum enumVar = nullValue;
    // ...
}
```